# How to render complex tables in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

Is it possible to render complex tables like this one in `rmarkdown`?

[image: Chi-square table]

I tried this code... it's as far as i can go:

```
| <br /> $X_1$ |     | | | $X_2$ | |
|----------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|-|-|-|-|
| |1|2|...|C||
| 1 | $O_{11}$ | $O_{12}$ |...| 1 | $n{1.}$ |
| 2 | $O_{21}$ | $O_{22}$ |...| 2 | $n{2.}$ |
| ... |...|...|...|...|...|
| L | $O_{L1}$ | $O_{L2}$ |...| $O_{LC}$ | $n{L.}$ |
|  | $n{.1}$ | $n{.2}$ | | $n{.C}$ | $N$ |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved a satisfactory solution with `kableExtra` using the following code:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

text_tbl <- data.frame(
   a= c("1", "2","...","L",""),
   b= c("$O_{11}$","$O_{21}$","...","$O_{L1}$","$n_{.1}$"),
   c= c("$O_{11}$","$O_{22}$","...","$O_{L2}$","$n_{.2}$"),
   d= c("...","...","...","...","..."),
   e= c("$O_{C1}$","$O_{C2}$","...","$O_{LC}$","$n_{.C}$"),
   f= c("$n_{1.}$","$n_{2.}$","...","$n_{L.}$","$N$"))
kable(text_tbl, "html", booktabs = T, col.names = c("","1","2","...","C"," "), escape=F) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F,bootstrap_options = "striped") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" Variável A", "Variável B" = 4, " ")) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  column_spec(2)
```

The result:

[image]